# Importing data with LinqToExcel

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-excel

I have an XLSX spreadsheet that I am trying to import into a `IList(of FinancialResults)` collection using VB.NET.

The spreadsheet is in the below format where I need to map the cells from the appropriate columns into a class.

**Spreadsheet**

[image: Spreadsheet]

**Model**

```
Public Class FinancialResults
    Friend Property MonthBudget As Single
    Friend Property MonthActual As Single
    Friend Property YearToDateBudget As Single
    Friend Property YearToDateActual As Single
    Friend Property FullYearForcastBudget As Single
    Friend Property FullYearForcastActual As Single
    Friend Property NextMonthBudget As Single
    Friend Property NextMonthActual As Single
End Class
```

**Code**

My initial view was to use [LinqToExcel](https://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/) which I installed via NuGet but I am having problems loading the data using the library. From reading the documentation on the website I found that this functionality can be provided by the [AddMapping](https://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/wiki/UsingLinqToExcel) method

```
ExcelEngine.AddMapping(Of FinancialResults)(Function(m) m.MonthBudget, "D")
ExcelEngine.AddMapping(Of FinancialResults)(Function(m) m.MonthActual, "E")
ExcelEngine.AddMapping(Of FinancialResults)(Function(m) m.YearToDateBudget, "H")
ExcelEngine.AddMapping(Of FinancialResults)(Function(m) m.YearToDateActual, "I")
ExcelEngine.AddMapping(Of FinancialResults)(Function(m) m.FullYearForcastBudget, "L")
ExcelEngine.AddMapping(Of FinancialResults)(Function(m) m.FullYearForcastActual, "M")
ExcelEngine.AddMapping(Of FinancialResults)(Function(m) m.NextMonthBudget, "P")
ExcelEngine.AddMapping(Of FinancialResults)(Function(m) m.NextMonthActual, "Q")
```

Then loading the data using the below Linq statement.

```
Dim var = (From r In ExcelEngine.Worksheet(Of FinancialResults)(excelPageName)
           Select r).ToList
```

**Results**

The code compiles and runs but the results are not loaded from the spreadsheet. All instances of the FinacialResults class are populated with 0.0

[image]

Figuring that the column mapping maybe at fault I queried the columns collection of the `ExcelQueryFactory` using

```
Dim cols = ExcelEngine.GetColumnNames(excelPageName)
```

Which returned the below.

[image]

I changed the column mappings to reflect these but again the results come back as 0.0 for all instances.

```
ExcelEngine.AddMapping(Of FinancialResults)(Function(m) m.MonthBudget, "F4")
ExcelEngine.AddMapping(Of FinancialResults)(Function(m) m.MonthActual, "F5")
```

**Question**

Is this possible using LinqToExcel given the format of this spreadsheet? If so what am I doing wrong? Should I be using the [WorksheetRange](https://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/wiki/UsingLinqToExcel) methods or loading each cell individually?

Is there another preferable alternative?

Comment: You say "I have an XLSX spreadsheet that I am trying to import using VB.NET."  To where are you trying to import the spreadsheet?  This may help me to help you determine whether there may be a "preferable alternative".

Comment: Initially to an IList(Of FinacialResults) object. It will then be mapped over to a database. I have had a look at using an SSIS package but I'm limited to what I can do on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible for LinqToExcel to read the spreadsheet you have because of its layout.

The easiest way to read it is to change the layout so the first row contains the column names like the picture below shows

[image]

Comment: Thanks Paul. I have gotten around it by reading each cell individually. Perf isn't great but its a once a week import so it's not a real concern.

Comment: I can't change the spreadsheet as its from our business and they are unwilling

Comment: @PhilMurray without changing the layout is there any way to read the data ?  i need a mapping between my excel and class so i can query against it.